# Django HTTP_REFERER refers to incorrect page

Tags: python, django, http

I have a django app that contains a link from the `homepage` that links to `View1` that redirects to `View2` and *should* redirect back to `View1`. However, the `HTTP_REFERER` header in `View2` sees the `homepage` as the referer and *not* `View1`.

**Homepage Template**

```html
...
<!-- This links to the LoginView -->
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
...
```

**Login View**

```py
class LoginView(views.View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            request.session.set_test_cookie()
            # This redirects to the create_captcha view
            return redirect(reverse('create_captcha'))

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**create_captcha view**

```py
def create_captcha(request):
    if not request.session.test_cookie_worked():
        return render("Please enable cookies and try again.")

    # This SHOULD redirect to LoginView but instead redirects to the homepage.
    return redirect(to=request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Expected Behavior: `homepage link` -> `LoginView` -> `create_captcha` -> `LoginView`

Actual Behavior: `homepage link` -> `LoginView` -> `create_captcha` -> `homepage`

**Question**: How do I make the `HTTP_REFERER` point to the `LoginView` instead of the homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the HTTP standard that says what should happen to a `HTTP_REFERER` after a redirect, so your code is going to be browser dependent. Also, `HTTP_REFERER` isn't always respected/enabled.

From your code it seems like you can just redirect to the URL directly:

```py
return redirect('login')
```

but I assume you want to handle some other cases.

You'd be better off adding a query string on to your URL such as:

```py
return redirect(reverse('create_captcha') + '?next=' + reverse('login')
```

Or a bit nicer on modern Python:

```py
return redirect(f"{reverse('create_captcha')}?next={reverse('login')}")
```

And in the captcha view:

```py
return redirect(request.GET['next'])
```